# Setting up rutorrent on 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, rtorrent

I'm getting the following error when loading rutorrent that's hosted on my 2010 Intel Core Duo 2 Mac Mini:

```
[23.06.2014 11:31:20] Bad response from server: (404 [error,list]) <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL /RPC2 was not found on this server.</p> <hr> <address>Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.4.24 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.5 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 Server at ***.***.*** Port ****</address> </body></html>
```

I followed the tutorial from this [thread](http://forums.rutorrent.org/index.php?topic=970.msg14381#new) to the T, and yet I can't figure out why I'm getting the error that I am getting.

Referencing the specific parts of the tutorial dealing with Apache and PHP, I did the following steps:

edited the following file:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

uncommented the first line and added the following two lines to the aforementioned file:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_scgi.so
SCGIMount /RPC2 127.0.0.1:5000
```

I then installed *mod_scgi* by entering these commands in terminal:

```
curl -O http://python.ca/scgi/releases/scgi-1.14.tar.gz
tar zxf scgi-1.14.tar.gz
cd scgi-1.14/apache2
sudo apxs -i -c mod_scgi.c
```

Then I tweaked Apache by entering these commands in terminal so that, according to the tutorial, Apache can load *mod_scgi*:

```
cd /usr/sbin
sudo mv ./httpd ./httpd.fat
sudo lipo ./httpd.fat -thin x86_64 -output ./httpd.x86_64
sudo ln -s ./httpd.x86_64 ./httpd
```

I then edited the rtorrent config file and added the following line:

```
scgi_port = 127.0.0.1:5000
```

I modified rutorrents "config.php" file to make sure these lines are as follows:

```
$scgi_port = 5000;
$scgi_host = "127.0.0.1";
```

Ran the following command to restart Apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k graceful
```

Ran rtorrent, then tried loading rutorrent and I get the same error as indicated above.

If anyone can help here I'd greatly appreciate it!